# How can I wrap unittest's assertRaises in another context manager?

Tags: python

I want to wrap the `unittest.TestCase().assertRaises` context manager with another context manager but struggle to find a solution. Here is my approach:

```
import unittest
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def wrapper():
    print("Before assertion")
    yield unittest.TestCase().assertRaises(ValueError)
    print("After assertion")


with wrapper():
    raise ValueError()
```

However, the ValueError is not caught by assertRaises and the output of running the code is:

```
Before assertion
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

How can I wrap `assertRaises` in another context manager such that it catches the expected exception but gives me the chance to do something afterwards ("After assertion" gets printed)? Can I do something like the following to catch errors that are not caught by the `assertRaises`?

```
@contextmanager
def wrapper():
    try:
        print("Before assertion")
        yield unittest.TestCase().assertRaises(ValueError)
        print("After assertion")
    except Exception:
        print("Did not raise ValueError!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context manager yields another context manager, so you need another `with`:

```
import unittest
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def wrapper():
    print("Before assertion")
    yield unittest.TestCase().assertRaises(ValueError)
    print("After assertion")


with wrapper() as another_manager:
    with another_manager:
        raise ValueError()
```

What you probably want to do instead of yielding the context manager is to put the `assertRaises` context inside your wrapper, and yield (`None`) from inside that:

```
import unittest
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def wrapper():
    print("Before assertion")
    with unittest.TestCase().assertRaises(ValueError):
        yield
    print("After assertion")


with wrapper():
    raise ValueError()
```